# Routing different ASP.Net Core Web API projects to the same base URL

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

My situation is that I have three separate ASP.net Core 2.1 Web API projects within one Visual Studio 2017 solution. Each project provides different functionality so at that time it made sense to split the functionality in different projects.

But now that I'm starting deployment and I would like to have the same base route each of the asp.net core projects (Base Route: http://domainname.com/api)

```
Project 1: http://domainname.com/api/Project1Controllers

Project 2: http://domainname.com/api/Project2Controllers

Project 3: http://domainname.com/api/Project3Controllers
```

Is there a way to setup/deploy this within IIS?

Comment: Use IIS ARR to set up a reverse proxy, and then any URL routing can be easily achieved.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out any helpful docs you have on setting it up would be great!